# XML and JSON tags for a Golang struct?

Tags: xml, json, encoding, go

I have an application that can output as JSON or XML depending on the HTTP request headers. I can achieve the correct output for either by adding the correct tags to the structs I'm using, but I can't figure out how to specify the tags for both JSON and XML.

For example, this serializes to correct XML:

```
type Foo struct {
    Id          int64       `xml:"id,attr"`
    Version     int16       `xml:"version,attr"`
}
```

...and this generates correct JSON:

```
type Foo struct {
    Id          int64       `json:"id"`
    Version     int16       `json:"version"`
}
```

...but this doesn't work for either:

```
type Foo struct {
    Id          int64       `xml:"id,attr",json:"id"`
    Version     int16       `xml:"version,attr",json:"version"`
}
```

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Go tags are space-separated. From [the manual](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/#StructTag):

> By convention, tag strings are a concatenation of optionally space-separated key:"value" pairs. Each key is a non-empty string consisting of non-control characters other than space (U+0020 ' '), quote (U+0022 '"'), and colon (U+003A ':'). Each value is quoted using U+0022 '"' characters and Go string literal syntax.

So, what you want to write is:

```
type Foo struct {
    Id          int64       `xml:"id,attr" json:"id"`
    Version     int16       `xml:"version,attr" json:"version"`
}
```

Comment: Could we use two json tag separated by space?

Comment: @MayankPatel No. The tags are read sequentially, and the first matching tag is returned.

Comment: Thanks. There is no way of parsing two json value in the same golang struct i think.

Comment: @MayankPatel No. You can pass comma-separated options, but only the first will count as the name.