# golang unmarshal complex json

Tags: json, go, unmarshalling

I have the following JSON blob, and I'm trying to decode it into Go.

```
["contig", "32", {"a":[33,41,35], "b":[44,34,42]}]
```

I believe that I have to model the data structure of the JSON.  I tried using a struct called `Line`:

```
package main

import (
"encoding/json"
"fmt"
)

type Line struct {
    Contig string
    Base   string
    PopMap map[string][]int
}

func main() {
    j := []byte(`["contig", "32", {"a":[33,41,35], "b":[44,34,42]}]`)
    var dat Line
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, &dat)
    fmt.Println(dat)
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

I got the following error:

```
{  map[]}
json: cannot unmarshal array into Go value of type main.Line
```

What am I doing wrong?

[Link to sandbox for trying out code](http://play.golang.org/p/ipcXbs5GUQ)

Answer (score 7):

The JSON input you specified is an array of different types, so as it is, you can't unmarshal it into a `struct`, but only into a slice of different types: `[]interface{}`.

```
in := `["contig", "32", {"a":[33,41,35], "b":[44,34,42]}]`

var arr []interface{}
if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(in), &arr); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
fmt.Println(arr)
```

Output:

```
[contig 32 map[a:[33 41 35] b:[44 34 42]]]
```

#### Filling the `struct`

Good, you now have the values, just not in the `struct` you want them to be. You can use [type assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to obtain the types you want:

```
l := Line{PopMap: map[string][]int{}}
l.Contig = arr[0].(string)
l.Base = arr[1].(string)

m := arr[2].(map[string]interface{})
for k, v := range m {
    nums := v.([]interface{})
    pops := make([]int, len(nums))
    for i, val := range nums {
        pops[i] = int(val.(float64))
    }
    l.PopMap[k] = pops
}

fmt.Printf("%+v", l)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/mApgu9Ner8)):

```
{Contig:contig Base:32 PopMap:map[a:[33 41 35] b:[44 34 42]]}
```

**Some notes:**

The "internal" arrays of the values of `"a"` and `"b"` are unmarshaled into values of type `[]interface{}` which you cannot simply convert to `[]int` or `[]float64` hence the `for` loops to iterate over them and use type assertion on each of their elements. Also note that the `json` package unmarshals the numbers into values of type `float64` and not `int` (because not just integers can be in the JSON text so `float64` is used which can accommodate both).

Also note that the success of type assertions are not checked in the above example. If the unmarshaled array has less than 3 elements, or any of the type assertion fails, a runtime panic occurs.

#### Using `recover()`

You can add a `defer` function which calls `recover()` to catch this panic (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/IZyx425RX9)):

```
defer func() {
    if r := recover(); r != nil {
        fmt.Println("Failed to unmarshal")
    }
}()

l := Line{PopMap: map[string][]int{}}
// ...and here comes the code that uses type assertions
// and stores values into...
```

#### Code with checks

Or you can add checks for the type assertions. The type assertion has a special form `v, ok = x.(T)` which when used never panics, but rather if the type assertion doesn't hold, `ok` will be `false` (and will be `true` if type assertion holds).

Try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/T4SZYmAFzB):

```
if len(arr) < 3 {
    return
}
var ok bool
l := Line{PopMap: map[string][]int{}}
if l.Contig, ok = arr[0].(string); !ok {
    return
}
if l.Base, ok = arr[1].(string); !ok {
    return
}
if m, ok := arr[2].(map[string]interface{}); !ok {
    return
} else {
    for k, v := range m {
        var nums []interface{}
        if nums, ok = v.([]interface{}); !ok {
            return
        }
        pops := make([]int, len(nums))
        for i, val := range nums {
            if f, ok := val.(float64); !ok {
                return
            } else {
                pops[i] = int(f)
            }
        }
        l.PopMap[k] = pops
    }
}

fmt.Printf("%+v", l)
```

Answer (score 2):

Because you have an array literal rather than an object, the best way to parse is by unmarshaling first to a slice of [json.RawMessages](https://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#RawMessage), and then go through the fields in the resulting slice:

```
package main

import (
     "encoding/json"
     "fmt"
)


func main() {
    j := []byte(`["contig", "32", {"a":[33,41,35], "b":[44,34,42]}]`)

    var entries []json.RawMessage
    err := json.Unmarshal(j, &entries)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }

    var contig string
    var num string
    var obj struct {
        A []int `json:"a"`
        B []int `json:"b"`
    }

    err = json.Unmarshal(entries[0], &contig)
    err = json.Unmarshal(entries[1], &num)
    err = json.Unmarshal(entries[2], &obj)

    fmt.Println(contig)
    fmt.Println(num)
    fmt.Println(obj)
}
```

This gives the correct result:

`contig
32
{[33 41 35] [44 34 42]}`

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/jcYvINkTTn

If you have control over the source of the JSON though, changing it to an object literal would be the most straightforward way to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON contains an array literal and you're trying to deserialize it as a struct. You need to change the JSON to an object literal where the keys are the property names of your struct.

```
j := []byte(`{
    "Contig": "contig",
    "Base": "32",
    "PopMap": {"a":[33,41,35], "b":[44,34,42]}
}`)
```

If the JSON isn't something you have the ability to change, then you will need to deserialize it into an untyped array and perform your own transformation into the struct type.

Comment: Does the Go JSON have any ability to override column mappings? (I expect such features from library like Json.NET; not sure if I should expect such in Go's implementation.)

Comment: Tags can be used to specify what key in a JSON object should be used to populate a property on a struct. This doesn't help with the JSON in the original post, though. An array is not a good format for this kind of structured data, where you have to remember that the item in position 0 has a totally different meaning than the item in position 1 and so on. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19885162/xml-and-json-tags-for-a-golang-struct